# Index error when adding Array to SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, keyvaluepair, sorteddictionary

I've been working on this code but have yet to see the results. It's giving me error message "Index was outside the bounds of the array". I read other posts with the same error but I couldn't fully understand nor apply most of the recommendations. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? Is there a better way to calculate this code? Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
     public class valProject
     {
          private SortedDictionary<double,int> mainsd = new SortedDictionary<double,int>(); 
          private SortedDictionary<double,int> valuesd = new SortedDictionary<double,int>();

          protected void Main()
          {
              mainsd = new SortedDictionary<double, int>()
              {
                  {500.10, 500}, {500.09, 1000}, {500.08, 2000}, {500.07, 3000},
                  {500.06, 4500}, {500.05, 5500}, {500.04, 6000}, {500.03, 7000},
                  {500.02, 8500}, {500.01, 9500}, {500.00, 10000}, {499.99, 9000},
                  {499.98, 8000}, {499.97, 7500}, {499.96, 6500}, {499.95, 5000},
                  {499.94, 4000}, {499.93, 3500}, {499.92, 2500}, {499.91, 1500},
                  {499.90, 550},
              };

              var maxValue = mainsd.Max(e => e.Value);
              var maxItemKey = mainsd.First(e => e.Value == maxValue).Key;
              var forward = mainsd.SkipWhile(e => e.Key <= maxItemKey).ToArray();
              var backward = mainsd.TakeWhile(e => e.Key < maxItemKey).Reverse().ToArray();
              int i1 = 0;
              int i2 = 0;

              while (true)
              {
                  var sum1 = i1 < forward.Length - 1 ? forward[i1].Value + forward[i1 + 1].Value : 0;
                  var sum2 = i2 < backward.Length - 1 ? backward[i2].Value + backward[i2 + 1].Value : 0;
                  if (sum1 == 0 && sum2 == 0) break;
                  if (sum1 >= sum2)
                  {
                      valuesd.Add(forward[i1].Key, forward[i1].Value); 
                      valuesd.Add(forward[i1 + 1].Key, forward[i1 + 1].Value); 
                      Console.WriteLine($"Forward:  {sum1}, Keys: {forward[i1].Key}, {forward[i1 + 1].Key}");
                      i1 += 2;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      valuesd.Add(backward[i2].Key, backward[i2].Value); 
                      valuesd.Add(backward[i2 + 1].Key, backward[i2 + 1].Value); 
                      Console.WriteLine($"Backward: {sum2}, Keys: {backward[i2 + 1].Key}, {backward[i2].Key}");
                      i2 += 2;
                  }

                  if (valuesd.Values.Sum() >= mainsd.Values.Sum() * 50 / 100) break;
              }
          }
     }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imported the project, no index out of bounds exception for me...

these are the results:

```
Forward:  18000, Keys: 500,01, 500,02
Backward: 17000, Keys: 499,98, 499,99
Backward: 14000, Keys: 499,96, 499,97
Forward:  13000, Keys: 500,03, 500,04
```

What might be going wrong is that your Main method is not static neither are the mainsd and valuesd fields. This would not create an index out of bounds exception though. The piece of code you supplied worked perfectly fine. Just in case here is the code that I ended up with

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace AProgramNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        private static SortedDictionary<double, int> mainsd = new SortedDictionary<double, int>();
        private static SortedDictionary<double, int> valuesd = new SortedDictionary<double, int>();

        protected static void Main()
        {
            mainsd = new SortedDictionary<double, int>()
              {
                  {500.10, 500}, {500.09, 1000}, {500.08, 2000}, {500.07, 3000},
                  {500.06, 4500}, {500.05, 5500}, {500.04, 6000}, {500.03, 7000},
                  {500.02, 8500}, {500.01, 9500}, {500.00, 10000}, {499.99, 9000},
                  {499.98, 8000}, {499.97, 7500}, {499.96, 6500}, {499.95, 5000},
                  {499.94, 4000}, {499.93, 3500}, {499.92, 2500}, {499.91, 1500},
                  {499.90, 550},
              };

            var maxValue = mainsd.Max(e => e.Value);
            var maxItemKey = mainsd.First(e => e.Value == maxValue).Key;
            var forward = mainsd.SkipWhile(e => e.Key <= maxItemKey).ToArray();
            var backward = mainsd.TakeWhile(e => e.Key < maxItemKey).Reverse().ToArray();
            int i1 = 0;
            int i2 = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                var sum1 = i1 < forward.Length - 1 ? forward[i1].Value + forward[i1 + 1].Value : 0;
                var sum2 = i2 < backward.Length - 1 ? backward[i2].Value + backward[i2 + 1].Value : 0;
                if (sum1 == 0 && sum2 == 0) break;
                if (sum1 >= sum2)
                {
                    valuesd.Add(forward[i1].Key, forward[i1].Value);
                    valuesd.Add(forward[i1 + 1].Key, forward[i1 + 1].Value);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Forward:  {sum1}, Keys: {forward[i1].Key}, {forward[i1 + 1].Key}");
                    i1 += 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    valuesd.Add(backward[i2].Key, backward[i2].Value);
                    valuesd.Add(backward[i2 + 1].Key, backward[i2 + 1].Value);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Backward: {sum2}, Keys: {backward[i2 + 1].Key}, {backward[i2].Key}");
                    i2 += 2;
                }

                if (valuesd.Values.Sum() >= mainsd.Values.Sum() * 50 / 100) break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. "Main method is not static neither are the mainsd and valuesd fields." was the issue.